# How to describe these expressions? Adblock

Tags: adblock

I have three expressions and I don't know how to describe them

1. ||ptracking.+(=adhost.+video_id=|video_id=.+=adhost)
2. ||(2mdn.net|storage.mds.yandex.net/.*video-an/|storage.yandex.net/.*video-an/|5visions.com/v/|dfs-linx-[0-9]*.dfs.ivi.ru/mp4-hi/|digitalaccess.ru).*.(avi|flv|wmv|mov|mp4|mpg|mpeg|webm|ogv)(\?.*)?$
3. ||^(https?://|//)?(www.)?([^/?]+.)?(lycamobile.com|mobilevikings.com|njumobile.com|orange.com|play.com|plus.com|virginmobile.com)

Comment: This isn't an answer, but it may be helpful: You can try the Filter Search here: https://blockadblock.com/search-adblock-filters.php Next to each result there's a pulldown that explains each filter.

Comment: Thank you for all your help